# Build a list from one text field into another then select to remove items from list

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to enter text in the lower text field, click Add to List and have it populate in the text area above. Then if you click the item in the text area you are given the option to remove it. So far I've been able to transfer the value of the text field into the text area but need help beyond that. A working demo can be found online [HERE](http://triplewww.com/cm/bs/base_bootstrap_textfields.html) and a JS Fiddle that doesn't work for some reason (can someone tell me why it works locally and elsewhere) [JS Fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/rMdLZ/27/)   This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td  colspan="2" valign="top">
    Problem List:<BR />
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="ProbAreaTo" ></textarea><BR />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ">Delete Selected Problem</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" valign="top"><p>To add a problem to the list, type it in the New Problem text field and then click &quot;Add to List&quot;. To remove a problem, click it in the list, then click, &quot;Delete Selected Problem&quot;<P>
    <strong>New Problem</strong><P>
    <input type="text" id="ProbAreaFrom">
     <P>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="ProbListBtn" onclick="ListProbs();">Add to List</button>
    </p>
</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    function ListProbs() {
    if (document.getElementById("ProbListBtn").onclick) {
    var txt1 = document.getElementById("ProbAreaFrom").value;
   ProbAreaTo.value = txt1;
    } 
   }
```

Comment: Why are you using a textarea for the list? Also, you need to [assign an event handler to a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event), not test it in an if statement.

Comment: A textarea for text makes sense to me what sort of form field should it be?

Comment: I questioned use of a textarea for two reasons: (1) A textarea is normally for _editable_ text. (2) You want the user to be able to select an item in that field to delete just that item - but a textarea doesn't maintain separate items, it just has a block of text, so how does a user select a specific item? (You could separate the items with newline (`\n`) characters or something, but it's still not very clear to the user how they select an item to delete it.)

Comment: ...so why not use a `<ul>` element for a list of items, with each item being a `<li>`? Then you can easily respond to click events on individual `<li>` elements to select them (you can apply a CSS class to show them as highlighted) and allow your delete functionality to know which one to delete. Or use a `<select>` element as in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A select box is used to store and remove newly created elements. This code is complete from the example given above, it does remove the element from the select box and also clears the input text box after you click add. Here is a working [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/Yazpj/1538/)

CSS

```
#sbox {
overflow: hidden;
width: 200px;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td  colspan="2" valign="top">
    Problem List:<BR />

    <select id="sbox" name="selectbox" size="5"></select>
    <BR>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="DeleteProbs();">Delete 
    Selected Problem</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" valign="top"><p>Instructions<P>
    <strong>New Problem</strong><P>
    <input type="text" id="ProbAreaFrom">
     <P>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="ProbListBtn" 
      onclick="ListProbs();">Add to List</button>
    </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function ListProbs() {
var x = document.getElementById("sbox");
    var txt1 = document.getElementById("ProbAreaFrom").value;
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = txt1
    x.add(option);
    ProbAreaFrom.value="";
} 

   function DeleteProbs() {
    var x = document.getElementById("sbox");

    for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
    if (x.options[i].selected) {
        x.options[i].remove();
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but your working demo does not work correctly either. It can only add 1 item, adding a second will just overwrite the first.

Im sorry but a textarea is not the right way to go as you want the area you placed a textarea to be selectable only, not writeable and editable otherwise it voids the purpose of having to add items with a single line textbox.

I would suggest using a select box with a size of say 5 e.g.

```
<select id="selectbox" name="selectbox" size="5">

</select>
```

Then, set the css for the selectbox to have `overflow:hidden;` so it does not display the scroller (You can then set the overflow to auto if the selectbox length is > 5 in javascript)

In javascript on your add button, you can do this:

```
    var x = document.getElementById("selectbox");
    var txt1 = document.getElementById("ProbAreaFrom").value;
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = txt1
    x.add(option);
```

This will take the textbox value and add it into the selectbox.
You can then easily code a selected item to be removed on the delete button call.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot and is a good start when I finish it I'll post the solution.